# Node.JS Mongo DB driver not splitting up bulk inserts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to insert about 100k documents with a single `collection.insert` call using the standard [Mongo DB driver for Node.JS](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/testdb', function(err, db) {
    var collection = db.collection('testcollection');
    var docs = [];

    var doc = {
        str: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet urna consequat quam pharetra sagittis vitae at nulla. Suspendisse non felis sollicitudin, condimentum urna eu, congue massa. Nam arcu dui, sodales eget auctor nec, ullamcorper in turpis. Praesent sit amet purus mi. Mauris egestas sapien magna, a mattis tellus luctus et. Suspendisse potenti. Nam posuere neque at vulputate ornare. Nunc mollis lorem est, at porttitor augue sodales sed. Ut dui sapien, fermentum eu laoreet sed, sodales et augue. Aliquam erat volutpat.'
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        docs[i] = doc;
    }

    collection.insert(docs, function(err) {
        throw err;
    });
});
```

However, i get the following error:

```
/var/node/testproject/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:242
        throw message;
              ^
Error: Document exceeds maximum allowed bson size of 16777216 bytes
    at InsertCommand.toBinary (/var/node/testproject/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/commands/insert_command.js:86:11)
    at Connection.write (/var/node/testproject/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:230:42)
    at __executeInsertCommand (/var/node/testproject/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1857:14)
    at Db._executeInsertCommand (/var/node/testproject/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1930:5)
    at insertAll (/var/node/testproject/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/core.js:205:13)
    at Collection.insert (/var/node/testproject/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/core.js:35:3)
    at /var/node/testproject/dbtest.js:15:16
    at /var/node/testproject/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:431:11
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:664:11)
```

Since the individual documents are clearly smaller than 16 MB and given the stack trace, it seems the driver doesn't split up commands automatically. How do I fix this, preferably without coding it myself?

Comment: Can you show your actual invocation. Not all of it of course but a summary of how you are doing this.

Comment: @NeilLunn I added a trivial example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Thx. Possibly not an answer here. But check your diver version and make sure it is current. Then I would add some code to check the byte size before the insert. And of course submit to JIRA. Also if you are able to, can you please test against 2.6 RC. Using the runCommand form as shown [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/command/insert/#dbcmd.insert)

Comment: @NeilLunn Using that will not help, because the `documents` array will still exceed 16 MB. I've submitted it to JIRA. I've solved it for now by writing a `bulkInsert` function that manually splits it up into 1000 items at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was asking the questions to clarify what you were doing, and as suspected the **documents array** does exceed 64MB.

You seemed to expect that was the limitation per document, but what you were not expecting is that your **whole** request is actually a BSON document.

This is part of the wire protocol for mongodb, and as such batch requests are subject to the same limitations, in that your entire submission cannot exceed 16MB in size.

If you look at the runCommand pages for the insert and update operations in the 2.6 [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/command/insert/#behavior), this is clearly stated.

So in essence, this is not a bug. You need to break up large batch requests, and keep them under the 16MB size.

Comment: Yes, but it is a limitation. For example the Python driver does automatically split commands up. Mongo DB itself only has the document limitation.

Comment: @Overv that may be one way of looking at it, but I doubt it will be popular. I wouldn't for example expect a SQL type of driver to do this sort of work for me in a batch operation, and I don't actually know of one that will. I think the accepted means are that, you are responsible for keeping things under the wire protocol limitations, not the driver.

Comment: Fair enough, as someone new to databases and Mongo DB it just seemed like something that should work automagically.

Comment: +1 For this to work automatically. I don't want to get into MongoDBs or the node drivers underlying code, I want to use the principles of information hiding and just make use of the MongoDB Driver API and get going. MongoDB is supposed to be a Big Data database and passing through the 16MB limitation up to this abstracted level in a driver is imho a missing feature. Change that MB to TB or even PB and you are talking.